# WooCommerce multiple forms returning values on same page to appropriate form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

Hoping I can get some help from the pros.

I'm working on implementing a simple code generator on the WooCommerce "order-details.php" page so that the client can go there on his own and generate his own software code. I am a beginner in PHP so I am stuck. In the code below, I am displaying a form for each product in the order. The client should be able to enter a number, and then receive a new number to unlock his/her software. This works but the problem is that I don't know how to have the value returned to the form it was generated from so the result is displayed on all the forms.

This is the form that gets created next to each product in the loop:

```
<?php if ( in_array( $order->status, array( 'completed' ) ) ) { ?>

<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>"> 
Req Code: <input type="text" name="req_code">
<input type="submit" name="<?php echo strtr($product_name, array (' ' => '-')); ?>" value="Generate License" />
</form>

<h2><?php echo $result; ?></h2>
<?php } ?>
```

When the user enters the code and clicks "Submit" these functions are called (at the top of the page). Depending on the name of the form submitted, the appropriate function is called:

```
if (!empty($_POST['PRODUCT1'])) {
    $result = test_input($_POST['req_code']);
    if(!is_numeric($result)) $result  = "Only numbers accepted."; 
    else $result = "Your PRODUCT1 activation code: " . $_POST['req_code']*1;
} 

if (!empty($_POST['PRODUCT2'])) {
    $result = test_input($_POST['req_code']);
    if(!is_numeric($result)) $result  = "Only numbers accepted."; 
    else $result = "Your PRODUCT2 activation code: " . $_POST['req_code']*2;
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
```

But as I said earlier, the global variable $result is updated and of course, shows up under all forms, not just the form that was submitted.

Hopefully, I've clearly stated what the problem is. Basically, how do I return a form value back to the form it came from, out of many? Am I doing this wrong? Is there a better way to do it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You’ll need to make the form “identifiable” by PHP first – f.e. by inserting an additional hidden field into each form that holds the respective product id. And then, when you are outputting your forms again, you compare the current product id with the one that was send with the form – and only output the generated code value for that one form where those two match.

Comment: Hi CBroe - I'm a bit of a novice. Any chance I could see some example code related to what I posted? Thank you...

Comment: Any other suggestions? I really need to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered my own question based on CBroe's suggestion. I added this hidden field to my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="formName" value="<?php echo strtr($product_name, array (' ' => '-')); ?>">
```

And then I display the result on only the form that the submit button was pressed on:

```
<h2><?php if ($_POST['formName']==strtr($product_name, array (' ' => '-'))) echo $result; ?></h2>
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Cheers!